# Hide duplicate in SQL Server Reporting Services 2008

Tags: sql, service, duplicates, hide, reporting

Duplicate data is showing on my report, I'm using this formula to hide duplicated rows:

```
=(Previous(Fields!PK_Field1.Value) = Fields!PK_Field1.Value)
```

How can I modify this formula so that instead of comparing the actual row with the previous, the actual row compares it self to the next one.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a distinct to your sql to remove the duplicates?

Comment: It does have a Distinct, but there are some rows that are almost the same but differ on one or two columns and not all the duplicates have the same columns that differ one from another.

Comment: Can you attach the report or a screenshot of the issue you are trying to resolve?

Comment: Steve, i managed to solve this by doing a "order by DESC", now it works, but sql reporting services instead of actually deleting or hiding the row it appears has a blank row.

Comment: Can you try adding an expression to the visibility property of your detail grouping?  Something like
    =IIF(IsNothing(ReportItems!Textbox124.value),True, False)